# Convert encoding in flash actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there any function like php's `mb_convert_encoding` which can convert an encoding to another?

I want to convert the utf-8 text, passed in a input field inside the flash, to iso-8859-7 encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, try [`flash.utils.ByteArray::writeMultiByte()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeMultiByte()):

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeMultiByte("Δ", "iso-8859-7");  // Capital delta
assertEquals(0xc4, bytes[0]);
```